# How to create Left View with 3d effect in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here I attached the images in link format .So you can understand very easily.I want to create 3d effect like check2.PNG link.Kindly Give some examples related my topic.

http://www.exarcplus.com/check/check1.PNG
http://www.exarcplus.com/check/check2.PNG

Comment: Hey @sures Try icarousal.,

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/VCTransitionsLibrary

or

https://github.com/applidium/ADTransitionController

Hope those help.

Comment: I want to create half view with 3d effect like flipkart application

Comment: If you understand how these classes work, I'm sure you can do it for a partial view as well.